# Selecting Random Item from List given probability of each item

Tags: c#, random, probability, n-gram

Sorry about badly phrased title....

I have an object called NGram

```
class NGram
{
     //other properties
     double Probability {get; set;} //Value between 1 and 0 
}
```

Now suppose I have a list of these objects such that...

```
List<NGrams> grams = GetNGrams();
Debug.Assert(grams.Sum(x => x.Probability) == 1);
```

How can I select a random item from this list while factoring in the probability distribution.

For instance, suppose `grams[0].Probability == 0.5` then there should be a 50% chance of selecting `grams[0]`

I figured I may need something like  `rand.NextDouble()` but I am at loss.

Comment: you want to select based off their probability value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a more generic way to do it (meaning you don't *need* to assert that the probabilities add to 1):

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public NGram GetRandom(IEnumerable<NGram> pool)
{
     // get universal probability 
     double u = pool.Sum (p => p.Probability);

     // pick a random number between 0 and u
     double r = rand.NextDouble() * u;

     double sum = 0;
     foreach(NGram n in pool)
     {
         // loop until the random number is less than our cumulative probability
         if(r <= (sum = sum + n.Probability))
         {
            return n;
         }
     }
     // should never get here
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Ah ha. I was missing the accumulative line to the sum. All works good now. Thank you for all the answers, but I used this one first :) William

Comment: Suppose you have  this kind of data {0.7, 0.15, 0.15} does this algorithm works!?

Comment: @FatihTürker Try it and see!  At face value I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: using IEnumerable for a param if you plan on enumerating it multiple times in the method is a bit of an antipattern.

Comment: Other answers have pointed out that the `pool` needs to be order by Probability in Ascending order.

Comment: @KellyElton No it doesn't.

Comment: @DStanley I ran some tests and you're correct that sorting is not required. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GANFnq

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list, order by Probability, ascending.

Sum the Probability field for all elements in the list. Let's call that sum **P**.

Get a random number between [0, **P**], let's call it **r**

Iterate the list while keeping an accumulate value of the sum of Probability up to the current element you are iterating (**pe**). End the search when find the first element for which **pe** >= **r**

The case of all elements in the array to sum 1 is now just an special case :)

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented as you said, but I've noticed this issue: Suppose I generate a random number of 0.955. Non of the items in the list have a probability of 0.955, so Probability value >= r is never true in this case

Comment: Forgot to say that you should accumulate the prob. while iterating, let me review it

Comment: Ok, it is edited with the correct algorithm. When checking the random value with the accumulated Probability you won't hit the issue you pointed out

Comment: Sorting is not required https://dotnetfiddle.net/GANFnq

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code

```
r = Get a random number between 0 and 1
sum = 0
i = 0
Loop  
    sum = sum + grams[i].Probability  
    If sum >= r Then  
        Exit Loop
    End
    i = i + 1  
End
i is the index of the random item in the list
```

The idea is to sum up the item's probability until the sum is greater or equal than a random number. Since the probabilities sum up to 1 and the random number is in the range 0 .. 1, you will find an item in any case. Items with a greater probability are more likely to be chosen.

```
∑P= 0 0.08     0.3 0.43 0.53          0.88  1
    +--+--------+----+---+-------------+----+
    |  |        |    |   |             |    |
    +--+--------+----+---+-------------+----+ 
i =  0      1      2   3       4         5
```

You can imagine each item to be of a length equal to its assigned probability. The algorithm is like randomly throwing a dart at a ruler of length one, with all the probabilities stacked up along the ruler. The probability for an item to be hit is proportional to its size (i.e. its assigned probability).

Comment: Suppose you have this kind of data {0.7, 0.15, 0.15} does this algorithm works!?

Comment: @FatihTürker yes it does.

Comment: @FatihTürker: The algorithm does not require the probabilities to be sorted in any way. You can imagine this to be a target. You shoot from a great distance in a random direction. The probability that a specific rectangle is hit is proportional to its area and we made those areas proportional to given probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<NGram> grams = new List<NGram>()
{
    new NGram() { Probability = 0.5 },
    new NGram() { Probability = 0.35 },
    new NGram() { Probability = 0.15 }
};

var rnd = new Random();

var result =
    grams
        .Aggregate(
            new { sum = 0.0, target = rnd.NextDouble(), gram = (NGram)null },
            (a, g) =>
                a.gram == null && a.sum + g.Probability >= a.target
                    ? new { sum = a.sum + g.Probability, a.target, gram = g }
                    : new { sum = a.sum + g.Probability, a.target, a.gram });
```

It gives me results like this:

[image: result]