# Is there a better way to calculate odds?

Tags: c#

I was writing a program that simulates the Lottery game called Club Keno, and I wanted to match the odds that they have for the Kicker. So what I have done is picked a random number between 1 and 10046, then depending on the number, I return the kicker value. If the random number was 1000, I return a kicker value of 4. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. And I realize it doesn't add up to exactly 100%, but those were the odds I could find online. They added up to 100.45%

```
public static int Kicker()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    int num = rnd.Next(1, 10046);

    if (num < 125) //1.25 percent chance
        return 10;
    if (num < 495) //3.7 percent chance
        return 5;
    if (num < 1120)//6.25 percent chance
        return 4;
    if (num < 1745)//6.25 percent chance
        return 3;
    if (num < 5745)//40 percent chance
        return 2;

    return 1; // 43 percent chance
}
```

Comment: Why 10046?  Why use an int at all?  You can generate a double from Random.  Also, why is your random instantiated in the method?  It should be static and class level, not method level.

Comment: It's in a class called Pick, which is responsible for picking draw numbers, player numbers, jack numbers, ez pick numbers, and the kicker.

Comment: .... because otherwise you will always generate the same "random" numbers if you call this method very fast(because the current time is used as seed for Random).

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that already, and I use Thread.Sleep() before I actually call the method.

Comment: @JosephThompson Using `Thread.Sleep` to overcome the random seed being the same is just horrible.

Comment: Ok, well I am a junior, so that's why I'm here, to get tips and tricks.

Comment: The percentages stated aren't right because you can't have them adding up to more than 100%. The first is actually 1.243..%.and the last is 45.51..%

Comment: @JosephThompson. You have multiple options: store the `Random` instance in  a static field in the class, pass it to the method as parameter and store it wherever you call this method(but then you might just move the problem from here to there if that code is called very fast from somewhere else). A third option is to generate the seed yourself, f.e.: `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`. The best option is to pass it as parameter(f.e. if you want to test this method you can re-use the same instance to get predictable results).

Comment: @JohnRC: Looking at the code comments - the percentages match the difference from the preceding value (495 - 125 = 370 => 3.7) etc which accounts for why the range of random numbers generated is 1 - 10045 (10045 - 5745 = 4300 => 43%). I do not know whether or not that is how that particular lottery calculates the Kicker value - so cannot comment on the validity of the code.

Comment: Honestly, just use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086513/selecting-random-item-from-list-given-probability-of-each-item) and adapt your code to fit.  Use a `Dictionary<int, double>` (instead of the custom class the OP used) to store your "kicker" and its probability.  It will take you like 5 minutes

Comment: @PaulF - The percentages would be right if the random number range was 1 - 10000, and I think the selection tests should be '<=' not '<'. So the first range should be <= 125 out of 10000 which is 1.25%

Comment: @JohnRC: I agree - which would make the last percentage 42.55%. I did wonder if the figures OP got were correct, if not the intermediate values need adjusting.

Comment: Sorry, no the percentages are not right even then. They should all be the appropriate proportions of 10000. You can't have probabilities adding up to more than 100%.  Incidentally, I think the tests should be ordered so that the most likely outcome is tested first rather than last, that would improve efficiency.

Comment: I got the odds from here: http://moonrakerrestaurant.com/special/club-keno/ near the bottom of the page.

Comment: If you are concerened about number of comparisons you can use the idea of binary search. Options 1) check 1120 first than go check 125 else go check the right against 5745 etc. 2) Construct an array [125, 495 ..., 5745] then use Array.BinarySearch which will give you the index. Then you can select points directly from the second array using the index you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an extension method for the Random class:

```
static T Pick<T>(this Random random, Dictionary<T, double> elementToProbability) 
{
    var totalProbability = elementToProbability.Values.Sum();
    var randomValue = random.NextDouble() * totalProbability;

    foreach (var keyValuePair in elementToProbability) 
    {
        if (randomValue < keyValuePair.Value) 
            return keyValuePair.Key; 

        randomValue -= keyValuePair.Value;
    }
    return default(T); 
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = rnd.Pick(new Dictionary<int, double> 
{
    { 10, 1.25 },
    { 5, 3.7 },
    { 4, 6.25 },
    { 3, 6.25 },
    { 2, 40 },
    { 1, 43 }
});
```

Note that the "probabilities" don't have to add up to 1 or 100 or anything in particular.

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out to implement this (since I'm fairly new at extension methods) but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to return a value. When I try to return random, it says "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Random to Int.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "When I try to return random"?  The way you want to use it is as follows:
`var rnd = new Random(); int num = rnd.Pick(new Dictionary<int, double> { ... });`

Comment: Ohhhh, ok, got it. I wasn't assigning a num to it, I was just using it. Thanks!
Works Great!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the page at [club-keno](http://moonrakerrestaurant.com/special/club-keno/) to check out the odds stated there, and if you want to have an accurate implementation then here are my findings and suggestions.

First, the odds stated are somewhat inaccurate, because they do not add up to a 1.0 probability for all possible outcomes, as previously noted. However, the statement on the bottom line that "Overall odds: 1 in 1.74" implies something: that's the odds of not getting 1. It turns out to be a pretty accurate sum of the separate odds stated for the numbers 2 to 10. So, if we take that to be correct, then the odds of getting 1 are actually 1 in 2.35081.

Therefore, I calculated that to represent them (nearly) accurately in code, then we need to represent the following odds out of 100,000

- 1: 42546
- 2: 40000
- 3: 6250
- 4: 6250
- 5: 3704
- 10: 1250

So the code would be something like:

```
var rnd = new Random();
:
public static int Kicker()
{
  // get integer number in the range 0-99999
  int num = rnd.Next(0, 100000);

  // check the ranges
  if (num < 42546) return 1; // checking for 0 to 42,545
  if (num < 82546) return 2; // 42,546 to 82,545
  if (num < 88796) return 3; // 82,546 to 88,795
  if (num < 95046) return 4; // 88,796 to 95,045
  if (num < 98750) return 5; // 95,046 to 98,749
  return 10;                 // 98,750 to 99,999
}
```

We are, of course, trusting that the probability distribution of the random number generator is flat across the whole range of numbers. If you suspect not, then you could mitigate to some extent by, for example, using a much bigger range for the random number, say 100x the size, then modulo 100000 on the result before applying the test:

```
int num = rnd( 0, 10000000 ) % 100000 ;
```